# How to calculate the distance between the atom pairs in MDtraj?

Tags: python, biopython

I want to calculate the distance between the two hydrogen atoms. I want to do this using the MDtraj module https://mdtraj.org/1.9.4/api/generated/mdtraj.compute_distances.html .

But I'm getting the ValueError:
[image]

Here is the code

```py
coord = md.load('alanine-dipeptide-nowater.pdb')
h1 = np.array([(4.259, 24,471, 0.81), (-0.008, 23.118, -0.407)])

md.compute_distances(coord, h1)
```

h1 is the coordinates of the first hydrogen atom and a second hydrogen atom.
The data file is  here https://github.com/mahesh27dx/molecular_phys

Can someone figure out why I'm getting this error?
Thanks!!

Comment: Can you share complete traceback of error?

Comment: From the documentation, `atom_pairsnp.ndarray, shape=(num_pairs, 2), dtype=int`. `h1 = np.array([[1], [2]])` might solve your problem where 1 is the index of the first atom and 2 is the index of the 2nd atom

Comment: @astrick I added the complete traceback error.

Comment: @OsmanMamun I tried this, but the error still persists.

Answer (score 1):

The argument `atom_pairs` of `mdtraj.compute_distances` expects a numpy ndarray where each row gives the **indices** (not the coordinates) of two atoms involved in the interaction:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import mdtraj as md

>>> coord = md.load('alanine-dipeptide-nowater.pdb')
>>> h1 = np.array([[7, 17]], dtype=np.int32)
>>> md.compute_distances(coord, h1)
array([[0.46388564]], dtype=float32)
```